# Scalatra set port on http server

Tags: scala, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I want to use scalatra for my http server mocks, I´m using gradle to run my bdd test.

I´ve been reading the documentation but I cannot find a way to specify the port where to listen without use scala.build, but again my problem is that my project is a Gradle project, since our project is polyglot.

Regards.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?  How are you getting the server started?  Scalatra examples from their website run an embedded Jetty ...

Comment: I'm afraid not finally I use colossus. Take s look to finagle server